# date and time settings dont show up properly in wordpress 2.8.6

Tags: datetime, wordpress

I have some problems while making my own theme for wordpress. Currently I'm making a comment system that was updated in wordpress 2.7 (you now that one with treated comments).

I'm following the codex and everything is fine except the date-time output of each comment - now it is looking like this: %A %B %e%q, %Y at %I:%M %p . Instead of showing me the date and time of the comment.

I've checked my Date Format and Time Format settings in my admin panel and they seem to be set as needed (Date Format: 2009/11/13 and Time Format: 13:30). Maybe there is any parameter that should be passed to the wp _ list _ comments() function?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the template that is displaying your comments.  Going to guess that display of comment_date is not coded correctly.

The Date and Time Format in your control panel does NOT typically control how the theme displays date and time information.

Also see: [Formatting Date and Time](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time)